# sitecore identify template type in treelist view

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have a treelist which allows an editor to define a list of links which is then output in a sublayout.

Depending upon which templates the selected pages use in that treelist field will determine the field values I need to write out.

I have a generic content page template where its own sitecore URL should be referenced but I then have a pseudo template which contains a field for a string URL and additional field params relating to to an external site.

In that scenario I don't want the sitecore URL I instead need its field values so as to concat a link to an external site along with the token details and present that to the user in the list of links.

Currently I have the code below but I need to include a condition that says if the template of the current GUID item is type 'SSO-Link' then don't retrieve its sitecore URL from linkmanager instead refer to a field called URL as well as a number of additional fields.

Thanks - current code below

```cs
Item[] selectedItems = treelistField.GetItems();

foreach (Item item in selectedItems)
{
    string itemName = item.Name;
    string displayName = item.DisplayName; 
    string url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
    string linkName = "Undefined";

    if (displayName != null)
    {
        linkName = displayName;
    }
    else if (itemName != null)
    {
        linkName = itemName;
    }

    if (linkName != "Undefined" && url != null)
    {
        htmlOutput.Text += "<a href=\"" + url + "\">";
        htmlOutput.Text += linkName;
        htmlOutput.Text += "</a>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to add this simple condition at the beginning of your loop:

```cs
foreach (Item item in selectedItems)
{
    string url = null;
    if (item.TemplateName == "SSO-Link")
    {
        url = item["URL"];
        // other fields
    }
    else
    {
        url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
    }
    // your code
```

Comment: Should it be "SSO-Link" maybe using guid here is better and then compare it with TemplateId?

Comment: @Anicho that is a topic for another discussion ;] I've seen project with hundreds of guids where no one knew which one was what, I've seen projects with `Constants` classes containing tons of guids constants. This code is only a pseudo code and should be amended in a way the rest of the project is built.

Comment: Ok fair point, and agreed that is another discussion! Your Answer resolve the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension for my templates and template items. Then I call a constants class for the ID of the template I am comparing to.

```
public static class TemplateExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDerived([NotNull] this Template template, [NotNull] ID templateId)
    {
        return template.ID == templateId || template.GetBaseTemplates().Any(baseTemplate => IsDerived(baseTemplate, templateId));
    }

    public static bool IsDerived([NotNull] this TemplateItem template, [NotNull] ID templateId)
    {
        return template.ID == templateId || template.BaseTemplates.Any(baseTemplate => IsDerived(baseTemplate, templateId));
    }
}
```

Constants

```
public static class Products
{
    public static TemplateID ProductSection = new TemplateID(new ID("{73400360-5935-40B6-88BC-350DC5B9BC90}"));
    public static TemplateID ProductDetail = new TemplateID(new ID("{9CD3D5ED-E579-4611-88E0-6B44C9D56F16}"));
}
```

Use

```
if (item.IsDerived(Products.ProductDetail))
{ if code here  }
```

Hope this helps.